# Why is static_cast needed in the gcc's implementation of is_nothrow_constructible?

Tags: c++, type-traits, libstdc++, static-cast

Taken from the GCC implementation of `type_traits` why is `static_cast` needed here?

```
template <typename _Tp, typename... _Args>
struct __is_nt_constructible_impl
    : public integral_constant<bool, noexcept(_Tp(declval<_Args>()...))> {};

template <typename _Tp, typename _Arg>
struct __is_nt_constructible_impl<_Tp, _Arg>
    : public integral_constant<bool,
                               // Why is `static_cast` needed here?
                               noexcept(static_cast<_Tp>(declval<_Arg>()))> {};
```

Comment: That inconsistency does seem weird

Comment: You should ask questions like this on the relevant libstdc++ mailing list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A type is nothrow constructible from an argument list if the invented variable *declaration*

```
T t(declval<Args>()...);
```

would be [well-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#unary.prop-8) and is [known not to throw exceptions](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#tab:meta.unary.prop). In the plural argument case this is equivalent (modulo noexcept destructibility, see [LWG 2116](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2116)) to the well-formedness and nothrow of the [*type conversion expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.type.conv)

```
T(declval<Args>()...)
```

However in the single argument case the expression `T(declval<Args>())` is treated as a [cast-expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#2), which can invoke [`const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4); the explicit use of `static_cast` restores the equivalence to the declaration form.

As a [concrete example](https://godbolt.org/z/_5g_ry), consider the types:

```
struct D;
struct B { operator D&&() const; };
struct D : B {};
```

Here a `static_cast` from `B const` to `D&&` must use the conversion operator, but a cast expression can bypass the conversion operator and so is noexcept. So omitting the `static_cast` would give the wrong result for `is_nothrow_constructible<D&&, B const>`.

Comment: So the `static_cast` is needed so that the expression is always treated as `direct initialization` instead of as `cast expression`?

Comment: @JoãoPires yes, that's right. It's still not exactly what's required by the standard because it's not possible to test noexcept of a declaration using the `noexcept` operator, but it's a lot closer.